# Error when citing definitions

Tags: citing, article, definition

I'm looking to cite the source of a definition, but there seems to be a bug. An example of something I'm looking to type:

```
\begin{definition}[\cite[Definition 1.4.2]{Hilbert10}]
   content
\end{definition}
```

It seems that the right bracket after Definition 1.4.2 is interfering with the right bracket after {Hilbert10}. Latex thinks I'm misusing \cite, but it's just not reading the entire line.

Comment: This is a FAQ: `\begin{definition}[{\cite[Definition 1.4.2]{Hilbert10}}]` with additional braces.